# Meaning of the term .of() in flutter

Tags: flutter

So I was wondering about the Command I use when I close an `AlertDialog`:

```
FlatButton(
  child: Text('Okay'),
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  },
),
```

What does .of() exactly do? I could not find anything in the flutter dev documentation (Probably because I was missing the correct search term)

Can anyone explain what happens there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the Flutter SDK the `.of` methods are a kind of service locator function that take the framework BuildContext as an argument and return an internal API related to the named class but created by widgets higher up the widget tree. These APIs can then be used by child widgets to access state set on a parent widget and in some cases (such as Navigator) to manipulate them. The pattern encourages componentization and decouples the production of information related to the build tree with its consumption.

In addition to `Navigator.of` (returns a NavigatorState) there are:

- `Theme.of` (returns a ThemeData containing the ambient theme settings)
- `MediaQuery.of` (returns a MediaQueryData containing information computed about the device screen size)
- `Directionality.of` (returns a TextDirection containing information about text display)

Of course Flutter has non-specific methods for looking up parent widgets from the build context:

```
context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<T extends Widget>()
context.findAncestorStateOfType<T extends State>()
context.findRootAncestorStateOfType<T extends State>()
```

so `Theme.of(context)` is really just a static shorthand for `context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<Theme>().data` and `Navigator.of(context).pop()` is really just a shorthand for `context.findAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>().pop()`

Comment: So is the .of command limited to those classes? In theory, I should be able to implement my own .of into a class if I got this right? For example, if I would want to access the Drawer of a parent widget. Should i be able to get it with Drawer.of(context)?

Comment: The methods I've referenced are the ones provided on Flutter widget classes by the Flutter SDK authors (there may be others, those are just the ones that came to mind). Of course you can define you own `.of` methods to do whatever you like for your widget classes, but IMO it would be idomatic to call 'Parent api lookup' routines `.of`. I've done this a lot in my own codebases.

Answer (score 7):

From the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html) of the `Navigator` class,

> Although you can create a navigator directly, it's most common to use the navigator created by the Router which itself is created and configured by a WidgetsApp or a MaterialApp widget. You can refer to that navigator with Navigator.of.

As a general rule, any time you see something along the lines of `Classname.of(someObject)` in an OO language, `.of` is a builder that returns an instance of `Classname` from `someObject`.